# inside my powershell script ,why i am able to reference a site column using its Display name , while can not reference it using its internal name

Tags: 2013, development, powershell, administration, site-column

sometimes i can not understand how i need to write a robust power script inside sharepoint 2013, specifically when it comes to site columns Display Name versus internal names.

now i have the following site column, where its internal name is `ItemNumber` while its Display name is `Item Number` as shown here:-

[image]

now i wanted to assign this field a JSlink, so i tried the following script by referencing the site column using its internal name:-

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://servername/
$field = $web.Fields["ItemNumber"]
$field.PushChangesToLists = $true
$field.JSLink = "~siteCollection/Resources/hideItemNumberinQucikEdit.js"
$field.update()
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

but i got this error on the 3rd line:-

> PS C:\Users***> $field.PushChangesToLists = $true Property
>   'PushChangesToLists' cannot be found on this object; make sure it
>   exists and is settable. At line:1 char:1
>   + $field.PushChangesToLists = $true
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

now i modified my original script so inastead of using "ItemNumber" which represents the internal name, i used the "Item Number" which represents the display name, as follow:-

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://servername/
$field = $web.Fields["Item Number"]
$field.PushChangesToLists = $true
$field.JSLink = "~siteCollection/Resources/hideItemNumberinQucikEdit.js"
$field.update()
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

and my script worked well. but still i am 100% confused. As i know that sharepoint understand internal names for the columns,, or it will look for internal and then display names,,, but what i can not understand is that when i use the column internal name the script did not work, but when i used the column display name the script worked!!

also as mentioned on this link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem

> For an indexer based on a name, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation first
>   looks for the field by internal name and then by display name.

so can anyone advice what is going on ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the Powershell is not showing any description related to the data type of the value . so I tried to check the parameter type that should be passed to `web.Fields` in visual studio and I found out :

The `web.Fields[fieldname]` accepts only the **display name** and not the internal name of the field as shown below.

[image]

Meanwhile, I tried to check the parameter of `Web.Fields.GetField` that it takes the internal name or field display name.

[image]

So if `web.Fields` takes an internal name it should be mentioned in visual studio as it's shown for `Web.Fields.GetField`.

So your above code will work only with the display name because of the `web.Fields[fieldname]` accepts only the display name as I mentioned above.

Comment: and what about the MSDN link i provide ? it say that it should accept internal names

Comment: the above link is related to SPListItem class, not SPFields , meanwhile my attached image from visual studio, you can try it :)

Comment: so can you adivce what is the differences between these (SPListItem & SPFields) ? i did not get your point

Comment: SPListItem represents an item or row in a list. & SPField Represents a field in a list

Comment: Additionally,  to make sure my answer , Web.Fields.GetField and web.Fields both defined from SPField SPFieldCollection as It's shown at my print screen , Meanwhile, at Web.Fields.GetField it mention both internal name and display name , but web.Fields it only mentions display name , so if you know only the display name you should use web.Fields , hope it's now clear :)